# jQuery counter with modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery counter with a modal window after some delay in a loop. It is working fine, but the issue that when a page reloads the counter starts correctly from 10 to 0 like 10, 9, 8... 0, which is what I need.

When the page doesn't reload, the modal window loads but the counter starts with 0, 9, 8, 7... 0. I want it to start every time with 10 whenever the modal window loads.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  function function_name() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myCounter').modal('show');
      var timeleft = 10;
      var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
        timeleft--;
        document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
        if (timeleft <= 0)
          clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      }, 1000);
      function_name(); // call function
    }, 10000);
  }
  function_name();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="myCounter" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <section id="content" class="middel-align form">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
              <h3> The download will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="field text-center">
                <a id="BtnOne" class="button" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Continue Browser</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page, the span wherein you update the value starts at 10, because you defined it to be so. This only happens once, when the page is loaded.
After that, the start value will be zero (from the last download timer).

To fix this, reset the initial value inside the span to 10, before executing your downloadTimer.

Add the following line (do not remove it from the downloadtimer-function)

```
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeLeft;
```

Here

```
var timeleft = 10;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeLeft;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() { 
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0) ...
```

Comment: //Counter modal
 $(window).load(function(){
    function function_name(){
         setTimeout(function(){
           $('#myCounter').modal('show');
            var timeleft = 10;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            timeleft--;
            if(timeleft <= 0)
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            },1000);
         function_name(); // call function
       }, 10000);
    }
    function_name();
});

Comment: I see the problem. You moved the line from within the downloadTimer function, to the new place. instead of moving it, copy it. The line should be before and within the function. (I'll update the answer acoordingly)

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
   function function_name(){
       setTimeout(function(){
         $('#myCounter').modal('show');
          var timeleft = 10;
           document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeLeft;
           var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() { 
             timeleft--;
             document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
              if (timeleft <= 0)
               clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            },1000);
         function_name(); // call function
       }, 10000);
    }
    function_name();
});

Comment: Have you noticed the change I made to the example code I posted?
I saw you removed the line `document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;` from the downloadTimer function, that's why your counter seems to be stuck at 10. (The field isn't updated, because of the missing line)

Answer (score 0):

you should place    timeleft--; after . following line

```
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
timeleft--;
```

Answer (score 0):

finally here's your solved code

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    function function_name() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myCounter').modal('show');
        var timeleft = 10;
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
        timeleft--;

        document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
        if (timeleft <= 0){
           timeleft = 11;
        }
     }, 1000);
  }, 10000);
}
function_name();
});
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95494/

Comment: But issue is when click on continue to browse, then modal window stopped loop. and shows again after refreshing the page. I want it show in a loop after delay.

Comment: may be you want modal open after delay again when closed. 
check this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95495/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer;

$('#myCounter').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    $('#myCounter').trigger('focus');

    downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
        timeleft--;
        document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
        if (timeleft <= 0)    
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  }, 1000);

}).on('hide.bs.modal', function(){

    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    timeleft = 10;

})
```